# jquery pass attribute value, then select and remove the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function deleteLogoOrTextbyAjax(rowID, tableName){
    alert(rowID);
    alert(tableName);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cycling/deleteLogoOrTextbyAjax",
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: { rowID: rowID, tableName: tableName },
        success: function (res) {
            $( "div[dbid=rowID]" ).remove();    //here i need help
        }
    });
}
```

passing rowID, i want to remove the div with the attribute 'dbid' that is equal to the passed value rowID.

```
$( "div[dbid=rowID]" ).remove();
```

the above code is not working

Comment: `$('div[dbid="' + rowID + '"]').rem` or `$(```div[dbid=${rowID}]```]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

concat with + symbol

```
$( "div[dbid="+rowID+"]" ).remove();
```